# Issue with declaring a variable of type vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray> for a VTK unstructured grid

Tags: c++, vtk, paraview

I am trying to store a scalar field in a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` using `vtkDataArray` in VTK 8.1, and ultimately write it to a file. I am compiling my code by Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. However, the compiler is not happy about the following line:

```
// Add a scalar field to the unstructured grid
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray> data_array = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray>::New();
```

I get the following error:

```
Error C2440 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray>'  mycode c:\vtk\src\common\core\vtksmartpointer.h 155
```

I think I have the required headers:

```
#include "vtkCellArray.h"
#include "vtkCellData.h"
#include "vtkDataSet.h"
#include "vtkPoints.h"
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkCellData.h>
#include <vtkDoubleArray.h>
#include <vtkDataArray.h>
#include <vtkUnstructuredGrid.h>
#include <vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter.h>
```

My research online found out that the declaration line for `data_array` should work but I have no idea why the compiler does not like it.

Could someone please help me? Is there any other way of storing a scalar field in a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` and skip using `vtkDataArray`?

Comment: You should post minimum, complete and verifiable example. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The details you've given aren't enough for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vtkDataArray](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataArray.html) is an abstract class. You cannot create an object of an abstract class. So try using `vtkFloatArray` or `vtkDoubleArray` instead of `vtkDataArray`.

Comment: Thanks Amit. It nicely worked when I used `vtkDoubleArray`.